# Golang sql.DB WaitCount greater than 0 even when there are enough idle connections in the pool

Tags: mysql, go

I am looking at the [DBStats](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DBStats) of a web application in Golang. The metrics is exported to prometheus every 10s by [sqlstats](https://github.com/dlmiddlecote/sqlstats).

In the application, `MaxOpenConns` is set to 100, and `MaxIdleConns` is set to 50. And when I look into the metrics, I notice the number of open connections is stable around 50. This is expected, which means we are keeping 50 idle connections. However, the number of `InUse` connection is hovering between 0 and 5, and is 0 for most of the time. This is strange to me, because there is a constant inflow of traffic, and I don't expect the number of `InUse` connections to be 0.

Also, I notice `WaitCount` and `MaxIdleClosed` are pretty large. `WaitCount` means there is no idle connections left and sql.DB cannot open more connections due to `MaxOpenConns` limit. But from the stats above, there seems to be more than enough of headroom for sql.DB to create more connections (`OpenConnections` is way below `MaxOpenConnections` ). The big number of `MaxIdleClosed` also suggests sql.DB is making additional connections even when there are enough idle connections.

At the same time I am observing some `driver: bad connection` errors in the app and we are using MySQL.

Why does the app try to open more connections when there are enough idle connections around, and how should I tune the db param to reduce the issue?

Comment: In the question above you have mentioned `active` connections. But in `DBStats` there is no parameter with name as `active` connections. It would be easily understandable if you can describe the issue using the terms used in the package you are using. For example by `active` connections do you mean `InUse` connections??

Comment: @SaiRaviTejaK right, will update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the number of InUse connection is hovering between 0 and 5, and is 0 for most of the time. This is strange to me, because there is a constant inflow of traffic, and I don't expect the number of InUse connections to be 0.

It is not strange. The number of InUse connections moves like spikes. Since you get stats only at every 10s, you just don't see the spike.

> Why does the app try to open more connections when there are enough idle connections around,

See https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#important-settings

"db.SetMaxIdleConns() is recommended to be set same to (or greater than) db.SetMaxOpenConns(). When it is smaller than SetMaxOpenConns(), connections can be opened and closed very frequently than you expect."

> and how should I tune the db param to reduce the issue?

Follow the recommendation of the [go-sql-driver/mysql README](https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#usage).
Use `db.SetConnMaxLifetime()`, and set `db.SetMaxIdleConns()` same to `db.SetMaxOpenConns()`.

```golang
db.SetMaxOpenConns(100)
db.SetMaxIdleConns(100)
db.SetConnMaxLifetime(time.Minute * 3)
```